# How to merge or join a stacked dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I cannot find this question answered elsewhere; I would like to do a SQL-like join in pandas but with the slight twist that one dataframe is stacked. 
I have created a dataframe A with a stacked column index from a csv file in pandas that looks as follows:

```
|           |      | 2013-01-04 | 2013-01-07 |
|----------:|-----:|-----------:|-----------:|
| Adj Close |  OWW | NaN        | NaN        |
|   Close   | OXLC | 4.155157   | 4.147217   |
|           |  OXM | 40.318089  | 42.988800  |
|           |  OXY | 50.416079  | 62.934800  |
```

The original csv had repeated what is in the 1st column for every entry like so:

```
|           |      | 2013-01-04 | 2013-01-07 |
|----------:|-----:|-----------:|-----------:|
| Adj Close |  OWW | NaN        | NaN        |
|   Close   | OXLC | 4.155157   | 4.147217   |
|   Close   |  OXM | 40.318089  | 42.988800  |
|   Close   |  OXY | 50.416079  | 62.934800  |
```

The original csv was the transposed version of this. Pandas chose to stack that when converting to dataframe. (I used this code: pd.read_csv(file, header = [0,1], index_col=0).T)

In another csv/dataframe B I have for all of those so-called ticker symbols another ID that I would rather like to use: CIK.

```
| CIK     | Ticker | Name                                           |
|---------|--------|------------------------------------------------|
| 1090872 | A      | Agilent Technologies Inc                       |
| 4281    | AA     | Alcoa Inc                                      |
| 1332552 | AAACU  | Asia Automotive Acquisition Corp               |
| 1287145 | AABB   | Asia Broadband Inc                             |
| 1024015 | AABC   | Access Anytime Bancorp Inc                     |
| 1099290 | AAC    | Sinocoking Coal & Coke Chemical Industries Inc |
| 1264707 | AACC   | Asset Acceptance Capital Corp                  |
| 849116  | AACE   | Ace Cash Express Inc                           |
| 1409430 | AAGC   | All American Gold Corp                         |
| 948846  | AAI    | Airtran Holdings Inc                           |
```

Desired output: I would like to have the CIK instead of the ticker in a new dataframe otherwise identical to A.

Now in SQL I could easily join on A.name_of_2nd_column = b.Ticker since the table would just have the entry in the 1st column repeated in every line (like the original csv) and the column would have a name but in pandas I cannot. I tried this code:

```
result = pd.merge(data, tix, how='left', left_on=[1] right_on=['Ticker'])
```

How do I tell pandas to use the 2nd column as the key and/or interpret the first column just as repeated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to do it the following way:

```
df = A
tix = B
```

```
ticker_2_CIK = dict(zip(tix.Ticker,tix.CIK))  # create a dict

tmp = df.reset_index().assign(CIK=lambda x: x['ticker'].map(ticker_2_CIK)) # use dict to find the correct value for colum 

# data was unclean, some ticker symbols were created after the period my data is from 
# and data was incomplete with some tickers missing
solution = tmp.dropna(subset=['CIK']).astype({'CIK':int})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to transcode from one set of identifiers (tickers) to another (CIKs used in the SEC Edgar database I presume).

I would

1. Turn the index column(s) into ordinary columns especially if these are multi-indexes, possibly after renaming the index columns

```
A.index.names=('Data','Ticker')
A = A.reset_index()
```

2. Use the map method to transcode the tickers to CIKs

```
transco = B.set_index('Ticker').CIK
A['CIK'] = A.Ticker.map(transco)
```

3. Eventually reindex from what you want, dropping unused indices

```
A = A.drop('Ticker', axis=1).set_index(['Data','CIK'])
```

As a step 2.5, you might want to remove the entries for which you don't have any CIK, e.g. by doing:

```
A = A[A.CIK.notnull()]
A.CIK = A.CIK.astype(int)
```

You could also merge after doing a `reset_index()`, but I would avoid that, as you might end up with uselessly large dataframes, as the result of the merge will have a names column. This can grow if you have many different types of data (Adj Close, Close, etc.).

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! At step 2. 'A['CIK'] = A.Ticker.map(transco)' gives this: 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' which sorta makes sense since neither "Close / Adj. Close"-price type (repeated with every entry) nor the Ticker (each listed once with every price type) are 
unique

Comment: It probably means your transcoding table is not 1-1. You have probably 2 rows with the same ticker and two different CIKs. In this case pandas does not want to decide on your behalf. You have to keep only one of the transcoding rules. A crude fix is to remove all rows with a duplicate tucker.